# Calculating time taken between rows in SQL

Tags: sql, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to SQL thus the question. I've the following table.

```
id | prev_state | curr_state | start_curr_state |selected_to_interview|interview_to_selected|
1  | APPLICANT. | INTERVIEW  | 2020-10-12.      | ?                   |
2  | NULL       | APPLICANT. | 2020-10-16       | NULL                | NULL.               |
1  | INTERVIEW. | SELECTED.  | 2020-1--20.      | NULL                | ?                   |
```

I've a set of 3 predetermined states of candidates - `APPLICANT`, `INTERVIEW` & `SELECTED`.
The table provides a record of candidates who transitioned from one stage to another.
The start_curr_state is the start date for the curr state - row 1 start of interview state.
Depending upon the states transitioned, I need to calculate the time taken to transition for each stage.

I understand the time is date diff `start_curr_state` for the `prev_state` - `start_curr_state`
But I'm unsure of how to calculate this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please tag with database platform

Comment: @OldProgrammer updated

Comment: You need to show what your final answer should look like so it is clear that your question is complete. From the look of things, a simple recursive CTE with a window function would do it but without knowing what the output is, can't put a definite sql for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `LAG()` , I assumed you have a key called 'candidateid' for each person:

```
select t1.* 
, CASE WHEN t1.curr_state = 'INTERVIEW' AND prev_state = 'APPLICANT' 
THEN datediff( lag(t1.start_curr_state) over (partition by t1.candidateid order by t1.start_curr_state) ,t1.start_curr_state) 
ELSE NULL END  selected_to_interview
from tablename t1
```

Comment: It will really help if you can write this in a switch case for one specific case like slected_to_interview. I'm new to SQL and still trying to wrap my head around this new learning.

Comment: @TannishaHill what about 'slected_to_interview' . please explain the whole logic ( maybe with examples in your question.

Comment: What I meant is that the logic will be something like `existing_table.withColumn("applicant_to_interview", when($"prev_state" === "APPLICANT" && $"curr_state" === "INTERVIEW, <this_lag_logic>).otherwise(0)`

Comment: There's no join, APPLICANT and INTERVIEW are current state in the same table as different rows.

Comment: yeah , fixed it after I read your comment

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues: the first, is to do "datediff" in your database. That's a simple question
The second is a classic question for good use of [Windows Function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/):
Specifically, the use of the LAG windows function.

Look at this example from the code (in the link mentioned):

```
SELECT id, --assumes it's the applicant id
START_CURR_STATE,
       CURR_STATE,
       START_CURR_STATE-LAG(START_CURR_STATE, 1) OVER
         (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY CURR_STATE)
         AS difference
  FROM TABLE
```

(fake code)

Please note: Since your CURR_STATE can be ordered correctly alphabetically, that works!
Also, sometimes you can do DATE-DATE, sometimes you need to use a function such as (DATEDIFF). That depends on your SQL platform, so you need to look it up